# Automatically putting selected people in a group on a course in moodle

Tags: excel, vba, list, moodle

I'm new to moodle and VBA in excel which made me wonder if I could use my list in excel to select people for groups on a course automatically since there are a lot of courses to get through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "Upload users" tool in Moodle to upload csv file that places users into groups. 
What you need is a csv file with columns (for example)
**username,course1,group1**
And then upload it in the "upload users" and select "Update existing users only".
This is very powerful tool and can be used for lots of different bulk actions on users.

You can find examples in https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Upload_users